# Retornar valor do DB em uma variável

Tags: c#

Estou tentando retornar o maior ID da tabela Orcamento em uma variável, porém ele me retorna um erro:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in MySql.Data.dll. Additional information: Referência de
>   objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Segue o código:

```
public void ultimoID(int ultimoid)
{
    int resultado;
    var conn = new MySqlConnection(stringCon);
    var sql = "SELECT MAX(id_orcamento)FROM orcamento";
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
    Object retorno = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    resultado = Convert.ToInt32(retorno);
}
```

Comment: Em qual linha dá o erro??

Comment: Nessa aqui: Object retorno = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: Precisa ver porque não está conseguindo criar `MySqlCommand`, o erro está lá.

Comment: Consegui rodar! Faltava isso: // Executa a cosulta
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read()) while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    string resultado = rdr["MAX(id_orcamento)"].ToString();
                    int resultadoid = Convert.ToInt32(resultado);
                    this.ultimoValor = resultadoid;
                }

Comment: Isto pode ter dado certo, mas é coincidência, e é gambiarra, porque este não é caso para usar o *reader*, o correto é o *scalar* mesmo. Ainda tem erro que a conexão não é fechada, o que pode ser o problema. E o código pode ser escrito em 1 linha.

Comment: entendi, eu tentei aqui desse jeito, mas ele dá o mesmo erro. Peguei só a expressão e executei no Mysql e ele retorna o resultado correto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque o tipo Object por var na sua variável retorno.

`var retorno = cmd.ExecuteScalar();`

Se não for isso, verifique se sua consulta SQL está gerando algum resultado.

Comment: valeu! Faltava o ExecuteReader();

Comment: @Jessf, se a resposta resolveu seu problema, marque ela como aceita; é a melhor maneira de agradecer (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)